# PHP parse HTML rows based on class name

Tags: php, html-table

How can I get all the rows with a specific class name such as:

```
<tr class="dailyeventtext" bgcolor="#cfcfcf" valign="top">
```

and then place each cell in that row into an array?

I used cURL to get the page off the client's server.

Comment: Can you define *place each cell in that row into an array* better? DOM nodes? Text content? Inner HTML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$matches = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr) {
    if ( ! $tr->hasAttribute('class')) {
       continue;
    }

    $class = explode(' ', $tr->getAttribute('class'));

    if (in_array('dailyeventtext', $class)) {
       $matches[] = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. Now how do I get the values of whats in each cell? Thank you.

Comment: @Anderson: Do you mean the text of each cell as separate array elements? Just `array_map()` the cols, returning `textContent` property.