# How to add a custom HTML class name to admin screen submenu items?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-admin

Here are these submenu items under the **Posts** menu

[image]

I inspected the code and found out that the markup of it is this

```html
<ul class="wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap">
  <li class="wp-submenu-head" aria-hidden="true">Posts</li>
  <li class="wp-first-item current"><a href="edit.php" class="wp-first-item current">All Posts</a></li>
  <li><a href="post-new.php">Add New</a></li>
  <li><a href="edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category">Categories</a></li>
  <li><a href="edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag">Tags</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I would want to do is add a custom class `my-custom-class` on the `<li>` tags (processed on the server-side) such that it would become like this

```html
<ul class="wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap">
  <li class="wp-submenu-head" aria-hidden="true">Posts</li>
  <li class="wp-first-item current my-custom-class"><a href="edit.php" class="wp-first-item current">All Posts</a></li>
  <li class="my-custom-class"><a href="post-new.php">Add New</a></li>
  <li class="my-custom-class"><a href="edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category">Categories</a></li>
  <li class="my-custom-class"><a href="edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag">Tags</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to add a custom HTML class name to admin screen submenu items?

Comment: It's not ideal, but unless you find a different solution you _could_ use attribute selectors instead. Granted, you want be able to target the `li`:s but rather the `a`:s; `.wp-submenu a[href="post-new.php"]` and so on.

Comment: The question is definite. Selectors are not an option for the said objective.

Comment: Could you please clarify the use case. **Why** would you want to do this? The reason for why this clarifications is needed is that there are many ways to target that element using client side code (CSS/JS). Defining your use case - what you are trying to achieve - would get better informed answers.

Comment: actually I just realized that the class can also be added in the `<a>` tags instead of the `<li>`, whichever works. The use case for this is for implementing [Material Design's ripple effects](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#buttons-section) which would require adding specific class names for the ripple effect to work

Comment: That ripple effect is done using JS so my JS resolution should work just fine as the effect won't work before JS is loaded

Comment: @JackNicholson I'm not so sure for now. The ripple effects work by appending new DOM objects with in the specific class name. The class name acts as markers on which doms need to have a ripple effect. The javascript library for the ripple then attaches those doms to the marked doms. As long as the footer script gets executed first before the the material  design script/library, it may work. I'm gonna have to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a str_replace on the html which will happen before the page has loaded:

Just need to work out the selectors or then parse it with [DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550079/php-parse-html-rows-based-on-class-name)

```
function callback($buffer) {

    $buffer = str_replace('wp-first-item', 'wp-first-item my-custom-class', $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}

function buffer_start() { ob_start("callback"); }

function buffer_end() { ob_end_flush(); }

add_action('admin_head', 'buffer_start');
add_action('admin_footer', 'buffer_end');
```

Comment: this answer is going to the right direction however it currently doesn't get the objective output

Answer (score 2):

We can actually do it with a simple plugin like this one:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: Custom Admin Submenu CSS Class **/

add_action( 'admin_menu', function() use ( &$submenu )
{
    $class = 'my-class'; // Edit to your needs!

    if( ! isset( $submenu['edit.php'][5] ) )
        return;

    if( ! empty( $submenu['edit.php'][5][4] ) ) // Append if css class exists
        $submenu['edit.php'][5][4] .= ' ' . $class;
    else                                      
        $submenu['edit.php'][5][4] = $class;

} );
```

We constructed it this way by spotting out this [this part](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/ba88762aa3a38b1c811a743c6f747822fe53850d/wp-admin/menu-header.php#L206-L210) of the `_wp_menu_output()` core function:

```
if ( ! empty( $sub_item[4] ) ) {
    $class[] = esc_attr( $sub_item[4] );
}
```

Here's how the modified HTML looks like:

```
<ul class='wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap'>
    <li class='wp-submenu-head' aria-hidden='true'>Posts</li>
    <li class="wp-first-item current my-class">
        <a href='edit.php' class="wp-first-item current my-class">All Posts</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='post-new.php'>Add New</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category'>Categories</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag'>Tags</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

where the custom css class is added to both the `<li>` tag and the `<a>` tag.

In general I don't like modifying a global variable, but there doesn't seems to be a workaround to add the class to the submenu via [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) or other explicit filters.

If you want to modify the css classes for the first level items (menu), you can e.g. look into the [`add_menu_classes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/add_menu_classes/) filter.

If you feel strongly that the css classes for the submenus should be directly adjustable via a filter, then you can [create a trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/), explain in detail why this is needed and e.g. suggest a new `add_submenu_classes` filter.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
function add_admin_class() {
    $find = '.wp-submenu li';
    $add_class = 'my-custom-class';

    echo '"<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("' . $find . '").addClass("' . $add_class . '");
        });
    </script>"';
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'add_admin_class');
```

[image]

Comment: this answer uses javascript to append the class name after the page has been safely loaded. What I'm trying to achieve is to append the class names right from the server-side process

Answer (score 1):

I have researched this. You cannot add css-classes to Admin Menu Items unless you hack the core files.

To add a new sub menu item you can use **delete_submenu_page()** and then **add_submenu_page()** but it does not allow you to specify a css class for it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

This worked for me.

```
add_action('admin_init','add_custom_class_adminMenu');
function add_custom_class_adminMenu() 
{
    global $menu;
    foreach($menu as $key => $value)
    {
        if('Posts' == $value[0])
        {
            $menu[$key][4] .= " custom-class-1";
        }

        if('Pages' == $value[0])
        {
            $menu[$key][4] .= " custom-class-2";
        }            
    }
}
```