# preg_match_all - exclude a word from the search php

Tags: php, regex

I want to exclude a class from this regex, for example "apple" or "apple-tree"

```
preg_match_all('/class[~=]+[\'"](.*?)[\'"]/i', $html, $matches1, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

How would I achieve this in php regex?

Comment: Use a negative lookahead.

Comment: That said, it would probably be easier to do it in the code that processes the result.

Comment: As in: [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff)

Comment: Would it not be better to amend the regex?  I still want to find those that do not contain the words and rename further down in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), **BUT** it's a slippery slope and I recommend using something other than regular expressions.

Let's start here (removing the unrelated regex for now, just for brevity):

```
class="((?!apple).*?)"
```

This *looks* good at first glance; it successfully ignores classes that equal or start with `apple`. But what if we want to ignore matches that have `apple` *anywhere* in the list? Because the class attribute can have many classes in any particular order.

```
class="((?:(?!apple).)*?)"
```

Nice, that takes care of excluding a class attribute where `apple` appears *anywhere* in the value. ([More in-depth explanation of this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/580587))

But, crap, our important customer Snapple reported a bug where their custom class names aren't working anymore.

You can see where this is going.

It's very possible that you have a more controlled scenario and one of the above will be useful. If so, awesome! I hope this helps.

For some alternatives to trying to do this by regular expressions, consider:

- [Loading and traversing the HTML via `DOMDocument`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7550101/580587)
- Similarly, using [DOMDocument + Xpath querying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13718745/580587) (you can do some *really* fun things with Xpath)
- For something more simple that doesn't seem to warrant all that nonsense, something like [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), where you can add in some business logic around a more generic matching pattern

Comment: What a superb answer! Thx

Comment: Thank you for the kind words.